# In R, how do I select certain columns that contain a certain value in a certain row index?

Tags: r, select, dplyr

Let's suppose we have a dataframe like such:

```
X <- data.frame(A = c(1,3,1), B = c(2,3,9), C = c(3,4,8))
```

```
[A, B, C]
[1, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 9]
[3, 4, 8]
```

I only want to select columns where its value in row 3 is greater than 5. In this case, only B and C would be selected. Furthermore, I only want to reference that row by its index. Like row 528, or 326.

What is the syntax for doing this? I checked online and it appeared dplyr's select would work... but I haven't figured out a good way to put it to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
row <- 3
X[row, X[row, ] > 5]

#  B C
#3 9 8
```

This select row number `row` and columns where value in `row` is greater than 5.

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
X %>% slice(row) %>% select_if(. > 5)
```